# How to find the best value of C in logistic regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the following logistic regression in scikit-learn.

```
log_reg_model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=50000,C=lambda_c,penalty='l1',multi_class='ovr',class_weight='balanced',solver='liblinear')
```

Right now I am manually putting differnt value of C (inverse of regularization strength) and checking the accuracy score. Is there any better way to do such that it automatically find the best C (regularization)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this operation using `GridsearchCV` to find the optimal value of `C`.

As follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

parameters = {'C':[1, 10, 20, 50]}
log_reg_model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=50000,penalty='l1',multi_class='ovr',class_weight='balanced',solver='liblinear')
cv = GridSearchCV(log_reg_model, parameters)
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
cv.best_params_
```